# List<T> vs array perfomance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, bytecode, generic-list

I try to set List< int > value

```
List< int > a;
//...
a[i] = X;
```

ilspy shows that setting compiles to:

```
callvirt instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::set_Item(int32, !0)
```

But this code

```
int[] b;
//...
b[i] = Y;
```

compiles to

```
stelem.i4
```

And was faster in 7 times with my benchmark.

As I understand virtual call is more expensive than stelem. Is it possible to use List< T > with array perfomace

**update**

Code:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N = int.Parse(args[0]);
        int M = int.Parse(args[1]);

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        int[] a = new int[N];
        for (int k = 0; k < M; ++k)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                a[i] = i * 2;
                a[i] -= i;
                a[i] += 1;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + ":" + a[N - 1]);

        var b = new List<int>(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            b.Add(0);
        }
        sw.Restart();
        for (int k = 0; k < M; ++k)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                b[i] = i * 2;
                b[i] -= i;
                b[i] += 1;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + ":" + b[N - 1]);
    }
```

Run and output:

```
> ./Console.exe 1000000 100

166:1000000
1467:1000000
```

Comment: You need the size of the collection to be dynamic? If yes live with `List<T>` otherwise use `Array`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

`List<T>` wraps an array, and it has some necessary overhead (in the first place because it is a class). Also operations like inserting and deleting are costly, specifically when it causes to reorder all other elements in the list.

If you don't want the overhead of `List<T>` or need the features like it's dynamic size, inserting and deleting, use an array. If you want or need to use `List<T>`, accept the performance loss.

You will have a hard time writing more efficient code than the .NET BCL team did, especially when it comes to re-sizing the array and other operations that can benefit from direct access to the underlying memory / OS functions.

Comment: Costly insert/delete is ok. But is it not possibly to optimize setting previously existed element? Ie setting list element without costly virtual call

Comment: This sounds as if a list is always less efficient what is definitely not the case. A list is much performant if you need to resize it continuously. OP is doing micro-optimization. _"If you don't want the overhead of List<T>, use an array"_ No, use it when it is appropriate, so use a list if you want to add or remove items and use an array if you want a fixed-size collection.

Comment: I think your measurement might be off (factor 7 seems a lot to me). There is no way you will get a better performance than the .NET team did using `List<T>`.

Comment: @user1312837 I don't understand what kind of code you're writing? If performance is that critical, IMO you shouldn't be using .Net at all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You are probably right. I altered the answer to emphasis this.

Comment: @user1312837: It is hard to measure this correctly. If you use a real profiler and multiple tries, what are the outcomes then?